# Encouraging people from Facebook buy/sell group to use free classified website

Tags: site-growth, facebook

So I have 3 buy/sell groups in Facebook with 20,000+ , 28,000+ and 43,000+ users. I wanted to encourage them to use a classified website and tried a lot of things for this, but so far I only get an approximately 1/100 registration (for each 100 users of the groups I get one registered user in the website) . Any idea/tip to get a higher rate for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can

- Add the link in the top banner
- Add the link in a pinned post
- Adding a Facebook page as administrator, which shows up at the top and the right and which has the link of the webpage inside
- Tell the users you are going to upload some of the articles to the website and repost them in the group and/or another Facebook page.
- Use an application like dlvrit which allows you to take a feed from a classified website, and configure it to post a link automatically and periodically to the Facebook group, as long as you are admin of that group. That way you can take the lastest product uploaded to the website and make the link to it automatically reposted to the Facebook group.